# Command for switching session in tmux

Tags: linux, tmux

I want the command to change the tmux session like how we change the window like next window and previous window

I tried both next session and previous session command but didn't worked

i want to switch between session with a single command like prefix + [ .

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps for **Switching session in linux**

- Open your **tmux configuration file** using a text editor

> ```
> vim ~/.tmux.conf
> ```

- Add the following lines to **create the keybindings**

> ```
>  bind [ switch-client -n
>  bind ] switch-client -p
> ```

- Save and close the file.
- **Reload your tmux configuration** to apply the changes

> tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf

Now you can use **prefix + [** to switch to the next session, and **prefix + ]** to switch to the previous session.

Remember that the **[ and ]** keys are the characters used in these keybindings. **You can customize** them to other keys if you prefer.